# IIS7 - .NET app displays fine on intranet, error on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, iis-7

OK, this used to work, but it appears to have stopped working on January 1st.

We have a .NET page that is displaying some data to our internal mobile users.  This page is set up with Anonymous Authentication in IIS7.  (Windows Server 2008 R2 is the OS of the web server.)  When accessing via our intranet, the page displays fine.  When attempting to access via our Blackberries, we get the following error message:

```
"Error: Page cannot be displayed.  Please contact your service provider for more details. (1)"
```

Is this an IIS error, an AT&T issue, or a Blackberry issue?  My Director is on my case about it, and I'm not experienced enough in IIS to know of anything else that would cause this functionality...

Answer (score 0):

You should check with your network ops team. I'm guessing that the blackberries are accessing the server from the external intranet (that's just a guess though) ... so have them double check that the domain/ip is accessible externally. That could be why you can access it from in the network.

Or if your blackberries are configured to access the network via VPN, I would double check that connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post the resolution to this.

It turned out to be a Blackberry issue.  With the latest OS, RIM combined the internal and external browsers into one browser.  Said browser attempts to determine if a given site is an intranet or internet site.  Even though the BES (sp?) was set up correctly, our service was still spotty.  Some people could enter our intranet homepage address and get the intranet; others got the web squatter site on the internet.  Since the page we were trying to access was nested fairly deeply in the directory structure, the web squatters didn't have a page with that name in their site.  That's why we were getting the error shown above.

Our resolution - we created a different BES alias to point to our intranet, and rolled that out to all applicable users.  Utilizing this, the browser didn't have to determine if we wanted our intranet site or the page on the internet; it correctly displayed the intranet page.